# What is the purpose of 手 here?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics

This is a lyric from a song:

> もし、今手が届かない

The translation I found is:

> Even if I can't reach my goal now

I understand that 手 means "hand", but what is its purpose here in the sentence? Shouldn't this also work?

> もし、今届かない

Does 手 here mean "goal" instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It more of less depends on the context, but [手が届く is a common set phrase](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%89%8B%E3%81%8C%E5%B1%8A%E3%81%8F) that means "to be able to reach", "to afford", "to become possible (to achieve something)", etc. Since it's a set phrase, a physical hand is not very important. I don't know where the word "goal" came from by just seeing this line.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! As a beginner I didn't realize 手が届く is common phrase. The full lyrics is [here](http://vocaloidlyrics.wikia.com/wiki/%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%80%81%E4%BB%8A%E6%89%8B%E3%81%8C%E5%B1%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84_(Moshi,_Ima_te_ga_Todokanai)#Lyrics) but I can see how the word "goal" is implied.